# Why is this CoffeeScript faster than this Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, node.js, coffeescript

I was solving a problem that asked me to find the sum of all EVEN fibonacci numbers under 4,000,000 and I noticed that the below CoffeeScript executed faster than the below Ruby.

#### CoffeeScript

```
sum = 0

f = (n) ->
  if n == 0 then return 0
  else if n == 1 then return 1
  else return f(n-1) + f(n-2)

console.log "Starting..."

for i in [1..4000000]
  ff = f(i)
  break if ff >= 4000000
  sum += ff if ff % 2 == 0
  console.log ".." + ff

console.log "Sum:" + sum
```

#### Ruby

```
sum = 0

def F(n)
  if n.eql? 0
    return 0
  elsif n.eql? 1
    return 1
  else
    return F(n-1) + F(n-2)
  end
end

puts "Starting..."

4000000.times do |num|
  the_num = F(num)
  break if the_num >= 4000000
  sum += the_num if the_num % 2 == 0
  puts ".." + the_num.to_s
end

puts "Sum:" + sum.to_s
```

It took nearly **6-8 seconds** for the Ruby script to find all even fibonacci numbers under 4,000,000 while it took roughly **0.2 seconds** to complete for the NodeJS execution of the transpilation of coffeescript.  Why is this??

```
$ ruby --version
  ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
$ node --version
  v0.10.25
```

Comment: you `ruby` script start from `0` to `4000000`, in coffee from `1` to `4000000` ))

Comment: since `0+x=x` it really doesn't matter - i noticed that too though `:)`

Comment: this is unfair play... `:)`

Comment: I suspect it is because it is not very idiomatic Ruby. This question was asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418524/fibonacci-one-liner; I suspect most of those answers will be far more efficient.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168718/what-blocks-ruby-python-to-get-javascript-v8-speed

Comment: thanks guys for posting your comments.  @MarkThomas per your comment, i have implemented that same ruby one liner and heeds the same results.  vkurchatkin, thanks for that read!  though it doesn't particularly answer my question, it was very interesting

Comment: What do you mean with "why"? Do you want to spot the slower lines? Do you want a faster implementation?

Comment: also @MarkThomas, this question is not a duplicate of that question as that is specific to trying to _optimize_ the code.  I am not trying to optimize. I am genuinely curious why the execution of the coffeescript is faster than the ruby script.  As far as idiomatic Ruby, that's a very subjective statement as this is idiomatic to me.

Comment: @mdesantis Once the ruby script gets into the millions, it starts to slow down.  Once it reaches 3 million, it takes about 10 seconds just to calculate the next number.  No, I don't want a faster implementation (which is why this is not aduplicate of Mark Thomas' question.)  I just want to know why it takes longer than the nodejs implementation

Comment: (I've updated the times.. I severely overexaggerated.  i did this problem last night and wrote the question today [for visibility] and didn't actually time it before)

Comment: Also, changing `.eql?` to `==` speeds up the thing from 6s to 2s

Comment: The answer is probably due to [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) which is done by the Javascript V8 engine used by Node, but which is not done by the default C-Ruby. This are probably different when using [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) or [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/), both of which use JIT compilers to speed things up. And your fib code is a prime example of a very well jit-able function (even more so when the compiler support tail-recursion, but I don't know if any of them support it).

Comment: @HolgerJust thanks for this.. so this is definitely a per-language limitation. I'll keep this in mind for sure!

Comment: More than per-language is a per-language-implementation limit

Comment: Less than a per-language than only a per-VM (aka. implementation) issue. Javascript VMs don't always have a JIT in the same way as Ruby or Python VMs sometimes have them, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's profile it using [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof):

```
# so_21908065.rb

sum = 0

def F(n)
  # using == instead of eql? speeds up from ~ 7s to ~ 2s
  if n == 0
    return 0
  elsif n == 1
    return 1
  else
    return F(n-1) + F(n-2)
  end
end

puts "Starting..."

1.upto(4000000) do |num|
  the_num = F(num)
  break if the_num >= 4000000
  sum += the_num if the_num % 2 == 0
  puts ".." + the_num.to_s
end

puts "Sum:" + sum.to_s
```

---

```
$ ruby-prof so_21908065.rb
 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 16.61     27.102    27.102     0.000     0.000 87403761   Fixnum#== 
  9.57     15.615    15.615     0.000     0.000 48315562   Fixnum#- 
  4.92      8.031     8.031     0.000     0.000 24157792   Fixnum#+ 
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000       70   IO#write 
  0.00    163.123     0.000     0.000   163.123        1   Integer#upto 
  0.00    163.122     0.000     0.000   163.122 48315596  *Object#F 
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000       35   IO#puts 
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000       34   Fixnum#to_s 
  0.00      0.001     0.000     0.000     0.000       35   Kernel#puts 
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000       34   String#+ 
  0.00    163.123     0.000     0.000   163.123        2   Global#[No method] 
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000       34   Fixnum#>= 
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        2   IO#set_encoding 
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000       33   Fixnum#% 
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Module#method_added 

* indicates recursively called methods
```

So the main culprits are `Fixnum#==`, `Fixnum#-` and  `Fixnum#+`.

As [@HolgerJust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908065/why-is-this-coffeescript-faster-than-this-ruby-script/21909876#comment33181982_21908065) noted, probably a "warmed" JRuby execution is much faster, due to JIT optimization.

Comment: so this is definitely not just me.. excellent.  Thanks for your help mdesantis

Comment: I marked this is as the accepted answer because it answers my question "why this node program is faster than the ruby script."  It is faster because of the 3 culprits mentioned above, `==, -, +`.  As well as @HolgerJust's comment regarding the Just-in-time compilation.  This compilation is faster for operations like this.